# Reading binary avro in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs, flume, avro

I am fluming a binary object to HDFS and have my flume agent and the sink setup looks like this

```
a1.sinks.k1.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.path = /user/%y-%m-%d/%H%M/%S
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.filePrefix = events-
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.round = true
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundValue = 10
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.roundUnit = minute

a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.serializer = avro_event
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.serializer.syncIntervalBytes = 4096000
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.serializer.compressionCodec = snappy
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.serializer.appendNewline = false
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.fileSuffix=.avro
a1.sinks.k1.hdfs.writeFormat=TEXT
```

Now I am trying to read this file(something.avro) from HDFS using this

```
data = LOAD 'something.avro'
      USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage();
dump data;
```

I keep on getting this exception, any idea as why I am getting that exception or is there another way to read binary avro object in a pig script without providing the avro schema

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Not a data file.
at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.initialize(DataFileStream.java:105)
at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.<init>(DataFileStream.java:84)
at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorageUtils.getSchema(AvroStorageUtils.java:718)
at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage.getSchema(AvroStorage.java:349)
at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage.getAvroSchema(AvroStorage.java:277)
at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage.getAvroSchema(AvroStorage.java:248)
at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage.setInputAvroSchema(AvroStorage.java:226)
at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage.getSchema(AvroStorage.java:434)
at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.getSchemaFromMetaData(LOLoad.java:175)
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem here, and I think is because we are reading avro binary datums, which are not the same as AVRO files.

You can try and read the files with the avro-tools using the fragtojson

`java -jar avro-tools-1.7.7.jar fragtojson part0.avro --schema-file schema.avsc`

and see it works! Post any findings if you manage to read it PIG.